# nanoff: Error E9007: Error downloading firmware file

Tags: .net, esp32, flashing, nanoframework

Can't flash nanoCLR

nanoff --platform esp32 --serialport COM8 --nofitcheck --update --clrfile "C:\NanoCLR\nanoCLR.bin"

I get an error:
"Error E9007: Error downloading firmware file."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnXau.png)

.NET nanoFramework Firmware Flasher v2.4.31+cc24c116a9
Copyright (C) 2019 .NET Foundation and nanoFramework project contributors

Using COM8 @ 115200 baud to connect to ESP32.
Reading details from chip...
OK

Connected to:
ESP32 (ESP32-D0WD-V3 (revision 3))
Features WiFi, BT, Dual Core, 240MHz, VRef calibration in efuse, Coding Scheme None
Flash size 4MB unknown from TENX (manufacturer 0x94 device 0x16406)
PSRAM: not available
Crystal 40MHz

No target name was provided! Using 'ESP32_REV3' based on the device characteristics.

Error E9007: Error downloading firmware file.

I tried to change the parameters, reinstalled different versions of the tool

Comment: The error is text - please include it *as* text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you from Russian or other country where Amazor CloudFlare block access for your country, you should use VPN. Using VPN me helps.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a local build of the CLR, the command you're using won't work.
Give it a try with:
`nanoff --platform esp32 --serialport COM8--update`